# Change event binding with PrimeNG Components and Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to dynamically bind the change events in the PrimeNG TreeTable, by declaring functions on my columns. The change event binding doesn't seem to work inside of TreeTable when I try to do it dynamically with my columns. I can get it to work if I declare the function on the angular component and the bind it.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-treetableedit-demo-wezv7m?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
 <p-treeTable [value]="files" [columns]="cols">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" ttEditableColumn [ngClass]="{'p-toggler-column': i === 0}">
                <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i === 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
                <p-treeTableCellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" [ngStyle]="{'width': i == 0 ? '90%': '100%'}" (change) ="col.change($event)">
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-template>
                </p-treeTableCellEditor>
            </td>
        </tr>            
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>

 ngOnInit() {
        this.nodeService.getFilesystem().then(files => this.files = files);

        this.cols = [
            { field: 'name', header: 'Name', change: (event) => console.log('Name Changed') },
            { field: 'size', header: 'Size', change: (event) => console.log('Size Changed')  },
            { field: 'type', header: 'Type', change: (event) => console.log('Type Changed')  }
        ];
    }
```

I can get the binding to work outside of TreeTable. Is there something about Angular Templates that I don't understand that is preventing this from working inside the Tree Table component?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z5gxtl?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: A bit confused here -- the first link appears to be working, as does the last. Can you clarify what about your code example there is not working as you expect?

Comment: The change event does not fire in the fist stack blitz

Comment: the event _does_ fire in the first stack blitz, but it happens on blur, not on enter or input change. Per MDN `(change)` doesn't always fire when the value of an input updates --> "Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration to an element's value." No sure what your end goal is (fire on any input value updates, fire on enter, etc), but you might try binding to a different event type like `(input)` instead of `(change)`.

Comment: So what is different between my two examples? I am binding (change) on input tags in other cases.

Comment: Functionally I see no difference -- the `console.log` fires in the same way in both examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed some important information in the PrimeNG documentation. Looks like PrimeNG component is capturing change. I need to use 'onEditComplete' event to capture and add some additional bindings to accomplish my goal.

```
<td [ttEditableColumn]="rowData" [ttEditableColumnField]="col.feild">
```

http://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/treetable
[image]